# A single user account on my Windows 10 PC can't access Google

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

A user account on my Windows 10 PC gets certificate errors when accessing Google from any browser. All other user accounts seem to be able to access it fine. And the problematic user account seems to be able to access other websites just fine.

The problematic user account is an offline account (not linked with Microsoft account) and is an administrator.

I have cleared certificate state on Internet Options but it doesn't work. The date, time, and timezone is set properly.

What else can I do?

Comment: Check for viruses and spyware.

Comment: @LPChip The scan quarantined something, but I'm guessing whatever changes it made need to be undone manually. Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly which errors ?